# How do I show this innerHTML script one time

Tags: javascript, html

Hello guys my friend Spiritx asked a good question on this website about how to show a objects contents using `innerHTML` so he shared this with me so I enjoyed this script so I decided to add this to my collections of scripts. So I accidentally press the button more than once and the objects contents keep on showing more than once every time I press the button so how can I show the objects output one time? Regardless how many times I press the button and I asked him if he knows how to show this one time but he doesn't know how here's the code to see what I mean.

```js
 function output_object(){ 
var student = {
    name: "Dave ",
    grades: [80, 85, 90 ,95]
    };
    
    for (index in student ) {
    document.getElementById("x").innerHTML += student[index];
    }
}
```

```html
<p id="x"></p>
  <button onclick="output_object()">Click</button>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the `+` sign after `.innerHTML`. With `+` you concatenate the new student with the previous value of `innerHTML`.

```js
function output_object(){ 

    document.getElementById("x").innerHTML = '';

    var student = {
       name: "Dave ",
       grades: [80, 85, 90 ,95]
    };
    
    
    for (index in student ) {
       document.getElementById("x").innerHTML += student[index];
    }

}
```

```html
<p id="x"></p>
<button onclick="output_object()">Click</button>
```

Or just use the properties' names directly

```js
function output_object(){ 

    var student = {
       name: "Dave ",
       grades: [80, 85, 90 ,95]
    };
    
    document.getElementById("x").innerHTML = student.name + student.grades;
    
}
```

```html
<p id="x"></p>
<button onclick="output_object()">Click</button>
```

Comment: I done that but it removes Dave how do I show all the contents?

Comment: If you have dynamically proerties which number you don't know you can every time at the start set the innerHTML to empty string. But if you have only this 2 properties, you don't need `for in` loop

Comment: Thank you Suren Srapyan!!!! Your my new hero now ha ha thanks it works.

Answer (score 0):

You could just check if the div empty. And if not, don't do anything. See example.

```js
 function output_object(){
 if (document.getElementById("x").innerHTML == "") {
    var student = {
        name: "Dave ",
        grades: [80, 85, 90 ,95]
        };

        for (index in student ) {
        document.getElementById("x").innerHTML += student[index];
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<p id="x"></p>
  <button onclick="output_object()">Click</button>
```